# obiee 11g ghost folder in subject area

Tags: obiee

I have made a presentation table in a subject area, but it was not ok, so I deleted the columns of that presentation table.

The problem is that there is a folder in the subject area in analytics and it is empty, but in the repository itself I don't see that folder. So it is like a ghost empty folder in the subject area in analytics.

Does someone know how I can delete that ghost folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we use multiuser RPD and that the folders where detached from the project. When I loaded the entire RPD (and not only one project) the folders appeared. So I was able to delete the folders

Answer (score 3):

If you Reload Metadata from the OBIEE front end Administration page, that should force it to re-read the RPD and remove the 'ghost' folder.